# How do you configure Web Proxies when using SSL locally with IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, proxy, web-config

I recently followed [Scott Hansleman's instructions on setting up SSL locally](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) using IIS Express for my Azure Web App. That seemed to work fine (was able to access pages that required SSL) until I got to a page that queries out to Table Storage. It threw the following:

> Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the
>   'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section.

So I added this to my web.config:

```
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault="False"/>
    </defaultProxy>
```

Now it throws a different error on the same line:

> The type initializer for 'System.Net.ServicePointManager' threw an
>   exception.

Drilling down in to that it references line 29 of my web.config and says:

> Required attribute 'type' not found.

However, line 29 doesn't seem to make any sense to me. Here is the relevant section:

```
25 <system.diagnostics>
26        <trace>
27            <listeners>
28              <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
29                   <filter />
30                </add>
31            </listeners>
32        </trace>
33    </system.diagnostics>
```

I thought maybe the problem was in the IIS applicationhost.config, which if I open in VS gives me a bunch of errors for missing elements but I think it's not using the right schema because I can't find any documentation that says those elements (mostly configSection elements) even have those properties.

This is a bit out of my element and I'm not having much luck searching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the error logs were correct. Even though it gives a warning of "Type attribute is not allowed" adding type="" to the web.config on the filter node fixes the problem. I can even remove the defaultProxy node that I had added.

Here is the new relevant section of the web config:

```
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace>
            <listeners>
                <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
```